# probability for the arrangement to start with a block of exactly k boys

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose that n boys and m girls are arranged randomly in order. Find the probability p(k) that the arrangement starts with a block of exactly k boys, for 0<=k<=N.

My solution:
Total Arrangement= (m+n)!
Arrangements with block of k boys=
choose k boys from n boys (nCk)
Those boys can be arranged in k! ways.
The remaining (n+m-k) people can be arranged in (n+m-k)!
So the probability would be (nCk)k!(n+m-k)!/(m+n)!

But I think there is a mistake in my approach. Because k can be 0 as well.
I am not sure how to approach this. Please correct me.

Comment: If it starts with a block of **exactly** $k$ boys, then immediately after those $k$ boys there *must be a girl*.  What you calculated was the probability of it starting with a block of *at least* $k$ boys.  As for possible issues with $k$ equaling zero, remember that $\binom{n}{0}=1$ for all $n$ and that $0!=1$

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes. But there can be 1 to m girls. right?

Comment: And?  Once you've picked the $k$ boys and arranged them, and pick a girl to provide at least some barrier between the initial block of boys and the rest of everybody, you can put the rest of the people there, possibly a girl next, possibly several girls next, possibly a boy next, doesn't matter... In how many ways can you pick a girl to follow the block of $k$ boys and then place everyone else?

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for guiding me to the answer. That made sense. This looks right to me now: (nCk) k! (mC1)(n-k+m-1)! for the numerator part.

Comment: seems to me the easy way of doing it is to note that the odds of the first chosen being a boy is n / (n+m), then (n - 1) / (n + m - 1) etc, then for the girl it is m / ( n + m - k)  - leads to [n! / (n - k)!] / [(n + m)! / (n + m - k)!] [m / (n + m - k)]

Comment: k = 0 occurs only if the first in the queue is a girl, probability m / (n + m)